# Redirect all URLs exactly except one URL that must be redirected to a different URL

Tags: htaccess, redirects, apache, 301-redirect, mod-rewrite

I must to change domain from `example.net` to `example.com`.

To redirect all URLs exactly (www and non-www) I use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (w*)example\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

But I need one URL from the old domain to be redirected to a different URL:

`example.net/en` to be redirected to `example.com/abc`, instead of `example.com/en`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to implement your more specific redirect first, before your "generic" redirect everything else directive.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^en$ https://example.com/abc [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Aside...

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (w*)example\.net$ [NC]
> ```

The `(w*)` prefix is superfluous here. This actually matches the domain `<anything>example.net` - so it still "works", but is possibly more than you need?

If you only want to match `example.net` or `www.example.net` (as stated in your question) then change this condition to read:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.net$ [NC]
```

Or, to catch mistyped URLs if you have a wildcard subdomain:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(w+\.)?example\.net$ [NC]
```

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm! You made my day!
Yesterday for the same question on #StackOverflow I get negative vote: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60735385/change-domain-redirect-all-urls-exactly-except-one-url-that-must-be-redirect-to/60751828#60751828